# Scheduling multiple executions of multiple bat files on different machine

Tags: batch-file, scheduling, scheduler, job-scheduling

I find myself in need of testing a multi desktop (between 2-4 different pc's on the same network) long running (each test runs for over an hour, and I cannot predict how long each test will take) program and I am trying to automate the system as much as possible (due to the large number of tests required)

Since I am testing for performance and the system uses collaboration (sharing of data) between nodes, it is vital that all machines run a test at the same time (system clock accuracy is enough, I am not looking at nano seconds) and that only a single test is run at a time (a single process is run on each machine and the next test can only be run once the process on each machine is complete). Therefore it would be ideal to detect when the system has completed execution in order to run the next test.

Each process is started from a batch file (which I prepare before hand). Note also that due to the fact that each process is rendering an image, all cores of the CPU are in use, thus any automation used will need to have low impact on performance.

I am proficient in both C++ and Java (the system in question is in c++), any help is appreciated. Thanks
(If I left anything unclear, please do ask, I do not have a lot of experience on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

You can remotely invoke tasks using the dos command SCHTASKS

so lets say each of your test machines has a scheduled task on them, when you are ready to run them you could have an application or script invoke each of the tasks practically simultaneously (within a second ?)

```
schtasks /Run /S nameofpctoruntaskon /U usernameofacct /P password /TN nameoftaskonpc /I
```